# Addition of two numbers by taking user input

Tags: clojure

How to add two numbers by taking user input?

```
(println "What's first?")
(let [num1 ( read-line)]
(println (str num1)))
(println (str num1))
(println "What's sec?")
(let [num2 (read-line)]
(println (str num2))) 
(println str(+ num1 num2)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(let [num1 (do (println "What's first?") (Integer/parseInt (read-line)))
      num2 (do (println "What's sec?") (Integer/parseInt (read-line)))]
  (println (+ num1 num2)))
```

[`do`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/do) blocks return result of evaluation of last expression. Then parse the result of [`read-line`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read-line) to a string and assign it to respectively `num1` and `num2`, then add the numbers and print the result.

Note there's no need to convert the result to a string before passing to `println` as you tried. If you would like to do it the `str` should be within the parentheses: `(str (+ num1 num2))`.

Comment: I copied the same code as you gave and it threw 'NumberFormatException For input string: ""  java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString (NumberFormatException.java:65)' error

Comment: You have to pass a number for this code to work :). Otherwise do a safe parse like this:

`(try (Integer/parseInt (read-line)) (catch NumberFormatException nfe 0))`. Then you return 0 when a user does not pass a string containing an integer.

Comment: I've passed a number. but got the same output error. I might be wrong. I've started learning clojure for just 2 days. Adding two numbers taking user input was the first step to it. But i found it is not just like any other language. everything is different

Comment: I put the code above in a file (e.g., `add_numbers.clj`). Then I run with `clojure add_numbers.clj`.

Comment: I'm running it in repl.it